# Progress bar with Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want show my total count as a progress bar with Laravel function. I wrote this function to get total count.

```
$countcomment = DB::table('comments')
                ->where('status', '=', 'Approved')
                ->count();
```

I want to show this count compare with 5000 as a percentage or value.my maximum count value is 5000.

Comment: What exactly do you want to count?? The total number of records in the database???

Comment: please elaborate. do you want to compute for its percentage?

Comment: @Capt. Teemo yes compute it and show in a bootstrap progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to compute for the percentage of your `$countcomment` you can use this formula:

`$percentage = ($countcomment/5000)*100;`

**Bootstrap 4**

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{$percentage}}%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's ok. how can i show it in a bootstrap progress bar